# Questions marks in my Wordpress text

Tags: wordpress, performance, .htaccess, utf-8, symbols

I've been handling this issue for quite a while now.
I'm working a on Dutch website (http://gboh.nl/). It's a site for a local political party. The thing is, the site went through quite a lot and I'm the third guy that is doing a new, easy design on it.
Sadly, for some reason, there seem to appear questionmark symbols in the text of some pages. I've read quite a lot about the utf-8 settings but I seem to have them correct. Also, the website didn't have an .htaccess file so I've added that.

If I use a clean browser (Cleared cache, incognito mode) I don't see the symbols on the homepage but when I visit another page and then go back to the homepage they seem to appear. Anyone knows how to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance! :D

Answer (score 0):

it is because of "Cache Enabler by KeyCDN". It compresses data incorrectly.
Go to its settings (whereever it is), and adjust it to UTF-8.
If it can't do it, just disable it.

Proof: 
Visit http://gboh.nl/?ss=ss - it will always show correct text. Because "Cache Enabler by KeyCDN" doesn't run if there is any GET parameter in URL.

Comment: You are a hero! Thank you so much :)
Get an extra cookie tonight!